# Creating an accumulating rollup

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have records in a table that have codes specific to a certain level and an amount attached to that level. They do not add up and that is not the issue.

I wish to create a query that sums up all the values by the level code plus those in the levels below it. I would also like the amount per level in the same query, but it is not necessary. I have create a sample table and output below. Does anyone have a good way of doing this? Also, is there an actual definition for this kind of roll up?

```
CREATE TABLE LEVEL_AMOUNTS(
    LEVEL_CODE    char(1)
    AMOUNT        integer
)
INSERT INTO LEVEL_AMOUNTS VALUES
('A',1),('A',1),('A',1),('A',1),
('B',1),('B',1),('B',1),('B',1),
('C',1),('C',1),('C',1),('C',1)
```

Output:

```
A | 12
B | 8
C | 4
```

Comment: I failed to specify that one cannot use the ascii values of the level code to order them or a specific ID to the code.

Comment: So can you specify how you want the "real" accumulation ? What's the "order" ?

Comment: Cause you can also make `<=` on `nvarchar`. For example "asdf" is smaller then "asde" or "bsdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
      select distinct level_code
      from level_amounts
     )
select l.level_code, sum(l.amount)
from cte
inner join level_amounts l on l.level_code <= cte.level_code
group by l.level_code
```

or

```
select l.level_code, sum(l.amount)
from level_amounts l
inner join (select distinct level_code
            from level_amounts) l1
on l.level_code <= l1.level_code
group by l.level_code;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25751/21)

Comment: I should specify that while I understand how using the ordering of the ascii values would work, my level codes are not in alphabetical order and not all are 1 char.

Comment: @user1281598 right, bigger string can also be ordered. And you can choose the fields used to make the `<=` join...

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 does not have cumulative sums.  You can do this with subqueries or joins:

```
with cte as (
      select level_code, sum(amount) as amount
      from amounts
      group by level_code
     )
select level_code,
       (select sum(amount) from cte cte2 where cte.level_code <= cte2.level_code) as cumamount
from cte;
```